# How preview Main.storyboard in different iphone/ipad screen sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'd like to look how my layout is on a different iphone screen sizes.

There are alot of tutorials but it doesn't work for me.

**What I've tried:**

- Opened Main.storyboard and opened the assistent editor
- In the assistent editor I chose "Preview" -> "Main.storyboard(Preview)"
- Now it should be possible to add different screen sizes by clicking on the add button on the bottom left of the assistent editor
  **but the add button is missing**

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is you assistant editor shown? If not go to View>Assistant Editor>Show Assistant Editor

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Open *Assistant editor* first, then hit *plus* button and choose screen size you want.
Take a look at my screenshot:

[image]